# my code shows "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable" but trying methods suggested on other posts don't work

Tags: python, typeerror

```py
def menu():
    choice = int(input("Do you want to add a new account(1) or view an existing password (2)? "))
    if choice == 1:
        *passwords()*
    elif choice == 2:
        *passview()*

def passwords():
    passwords = [[], [],[]]

    password_left = True
    while password_left:
        passwords[0] = input("Enter the account name: ")  
        passwords[1] = input("Enter the Username: ")
        passwords[2] = input("Enter the Password: ")
        print("Would you like to enter another account? Y/N? ")
        answer = input().upper()
        if answer == "N":
            password_left = False
        *menu()*

def passview():
    account = input("Which account would you like to find the password for?")
    location = passwords[2].index(account1)
    *print("The password is", passwords[2])*

*menu()*
```

I have used this code to create a (albeit temporary) password manager but the lines in italicts do not seem to want to work.

I expected that, it should bring the password from the 2D list and display it but instead it shows, as does the title, "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable". I also tried changing the values from, e.g. passwords[2] to password[2] but it still didn't work.

Comment: You probably don't want to call a variables `passwords` inside a function called `passwords`. That's confusing in general and is (probably) causing this problem in particular.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `passwords` is a function, but you seem to be using it as a list? Do you want to return the list out of the function?

Comment: Note that I wouldn't call passwords() from menu() and then menu() from passwords() - that is circular and hard to think about. Just return from passwords.

Comment: `passwords` is a local variable inside the `passwords()` function. You can't refer to it from other functions.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to restructure a bit. Consider the three functions you have as black boxes who are only allowed to pass data in and out from each other, rather than sharing information freely. Designing in this way helps clarify purpose of functions and makes reasoning about your program more simple.

```py
def menu():
    # takes no inputs, gives no outputs. Could be called "main," really!

def passwords():
    # create one or more passwords. Maybe call this create_passwords?
    # this will have to output some list of password objects. A triple, maybe?
    # (account_name, username, password)?

def passview():
    # gives the password for a given account.
    # this will have to output the password for that account.
```

Given this, I'd reformat as:

```py
def main():
    passwords = dict()  # let's model the password database as a
                        # dictionary from account name to (username, password)
    while True:  # it's the main loop, never leave
        print("""\
1. Add new account
2. View existing account""")
        choice = input(" > ")
        if choice == '1':
            while True:
                # hand create_password the account names that exist so
                # it can check for duplicates
                account_name, username, password = create_password(passwords.keys())
                passwords[account_name] = (username, password)
                if input("Add another user? (y/n)").lower() != 'y':
                    break  # break from the inner while loop
        elif choice == '2':
            account_name = input("What account name do you want to view? ")
            view_password(passwords.get(account_name))

def create_password(existing_account_names):
    while True:
        account_name = input("Account name: ")
        if account_name in existing_account_names:
            print("That account name already exists.")
            if input("Do you want to replace it? (y/n) ").lower == 'y':
                break
        else:
            break
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    return (account_name, username, password)

def view_password(account_info):
    if account_info is None:
        print("No such account")
        return
    username, password = account_info
    print(f"username: {username}\npassword: {password}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note now that `main` runs the whole loop, owns the password database, and hands the relevant information to its subordinate functions. Those functions will take in either the username and password (in the case of view_password) or a list of all account names (in the case of create_password) because *that's all they need to know how to do*.

Comment: The usual caveats about password handling are being omitted here, but consider that you never want to store your password in plaintext, so you should be looking into encrypting the password wherever it's held in memory and only decrypting it at the last second before displaying it.